# Проверка !window.jQuery и динамическая загрузка библиотеки

Tags: jquery, javascript

Пишу простой виджет типа последних твитов для новой социальной сети, виджет будет встраиваться на сторонних сайтах. Сам виджет работает нормально, но если на сайте нет jQuery, то мы загружаем его динамически

```
if(!window.jQuery){
            var jqScript = document.createElement('script');
            jqScript.type = 'text/javascript';
            jqScript.async = true;
            jqScript.src = 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js';
            var firstScript = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
            firstScript.parentNode.insertBefore(jqScript, firstScript);
        }
```

Если после этого скрипта вызвать jQuery, то библиотека не работает, а сам $ не определен. Вопрос как заставить (или как правильно вызвать следующие функции, которые используют jQuery), которые бы дождались бы загрузки библиотеки, если ее нет на сайте или может как-то по другому надо динамически загружать саму библиотеку?

Comment: в jqScript нужно добавить событие onload и только на его срабатывание можно пользоватся jQuery, раньше - нет

Comment: да так и сделал уже, спасибо

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Я делаю просто. Может и не элегантно, но работает сто процентов

```
!window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"><\/script>');
```

Comment: немного не то, скрипт будет вставляться в любое место страницы и у меня этот вариант не сработал, я дописал 

jqScript.onload = function(){
    StockFriends_LMSGW.init();
   }

и теперь все запускается после загрузки библиотеки

Comment: @Deonis, а это, зачем там слэш экранировать? о_О (`<\/script>`)

Comment: Если не заэкранировать, то на странице выведится "');"

Comment: а лучше `!window.jQuery && document.write('<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"><\/script>');`