# Синхронное подключение jQuery

Tags: jquery

Я к странице подключаю javascript 
<script  type="text/javascript" src="http://site.ru/chat/iframe.js"></script>

В iframe.js я подключаю jQuery.

iframe.js:

```
document.write("<script  type='text/javascript' src='jquery.js'></script>");
//И вот здесь мне нужно чтобы jquery уже работал 
$('#id_pic').show();
//Но он не работает, так ка ещё не загрузился
```

Вопрос, как в скрипте iframe.js подключить jquery чтобы его можно было использовать в этом же скрипте.

PS: Я хочу подключать jQuery именно в iframe.js, а не в главной странице!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[тут был похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/97695/%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-window-jquery-%D0%B8-%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%B1%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D0%B8)